# Pandas save to sql DF with XML column

Tags: mysql, xml, pandas

I have a simple DF with one column holding an xml per row. When I try to save to sql an error occurs:

```
 OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

if I delete the column with XML before saving there is no problem and the rest of the DF is saved into the DB. Also, if I save the DF to csv the xml column becomes a mess, it divides itself across other columns.

If I save the df to a txt file, the structure of the xml file is:

```
 "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><result final=""true"" timestamp=""2018-06-12T16:49:28.359-04:00"" transaction_id=""6T32ZH5"" xmlns=""http://cp.com/rules/client""><client id=""IP0000000""><quoteback name=""integrator"">HGH</quoteback></client><messages><message code=""ER"" type=""General"">SECURITY ALERT message(s) found.</message><message type=""General"">ORDER NUMBER: UYH90ZH5</message></messages><order_dataset><subjects><subject id=""S1""><name yada yada
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: *When I try to save to sql* ... *Also, if I save the DF to csv* -where is your attempted code? And please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE myTable` output of your table so we can see column types.

Comment: hi Parfait, I just solved this, the XML column is heavy, so I had to reduce the chunksize to 250, it was 1000 before.